# DatePlus and DateList are inconsistent with numerical handling of the final element

Tags: date-and-time

If you run this code you will see that `DatePlus` and `DateList` are inconsistent in the format of the lowest order element of the date list.

```
DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}] === DateList["2012-6-1"]
DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}] == DateList["2012-6-1"]
DateList[DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}]] === DateList["2012-6-1"]
DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}] // FullForm
DateList["2012-6-1"] // FullForm
DateList[DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}] ] // FullForm
```

This leads to issues when you try to locate elements in a list as follows:

```
Position[{DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}]}, DateList["2012-6-1"]]
Position[{DateList[DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1" ], {5, "Month"}]]}, DateList["2012-6-1"]]
```

What is even more annoying is that I have found that wrapping a date generated by `DatePlus` in `DateList` doesn't always fix the problem and I can not tell what circumstances are required to make it work and not work.

Any insight would be appreciated.  I may try to open a case with Wolfram, but my past experiences with their support team have been an unsatisfactory use of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note yourself `Equal` handles the problem, and in fact that is typically how these cases are handled:

```
Position[
  {DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]}, 
  x_ /; x == DateList["2012-6-1"]
]

Position[
  {DateList[DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]]}, 
  x_ /; x == DateList["2012-6-1"]
]
```

> ```
> {{1}}
>
> {{1}}
> ```

If you prefer `PatternTest`:

```
Position[
  {DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]}, 
  _?(# == DateList["2012-6-1"] &)
]

Position[
  {DateList[DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]]}, 
  _?(# == DateList["2012-6-1"] &)
]
```

> ```
> {{1}}
>
> {{1}}
> ```

Comment: Not sure of the etiquette here, but thanks for the responses, that's just what I needed.

Comment: @vandel you're welcome, and thanks.  The etiquette is to Accept (check mark) an answer that fully satisfies the question, just as you did.

Answer (score 4):

These issues revolving around casting to integer vs. float abound whenever translating data to/from external formats like Excel.

In all cases, projecting away the time information from the date proper with `Take[#, 3]&` or `Drop[#, -3]` solves your issues, but it is a hack nevertheless.

```
Take[#, 3] &@DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}] === Take[#, 3] &@DateList["2012-6-1"]
```

yields `True` and

```
Position[{Take[#, 3] &@DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]}, 
 Take[#, 3] &@DateList["2012-6-1"]]
```

yields `{{1}}`

Of course, `Round` also works:

```
Position[{DatePlus[DateList["2012-1-1"], {5, "Month"}]}, 
 Round /@ DateList["2012-6-1"]]
(* {{1}} *)
```

If you do contact WRI again, I found that they're helpful but resource-constrained and typically promise to put your suggestion on their feature implementation queue. Perhaps referencing this link would help, as these issues are nagging in data analysis.